# Shortest path on 4x4 grid c++

Tags: c++, shortest-path

I saw that there was another question almost just like this but the answer didn't do what I want it to.

This is for an assignment.  I have a 4x4 grid and a users inputted starting and ending (x,y) coordinates.  I need to send this info from main to a create_path function which calculates the shortest path then sends it to another function that prints the grid step by step of the markers location until it makes it to the wanted coordinate. I can't use arrays and I have to have main, create_path, and print_path.  The marker can only go up, down, left, and right.

So I really have no clue what to do. I thought about creating a variable for each cell in the grid but didn't know where to go from there.  If somebody knows a quick solution that only uses main and one other function that is okay because I am running out of time.

You don't need to see main because it just shows the user the grid and asks them for input then sends the input to this function:

```
void create_path(int xStart, int xEnd, int yStart, int yEnd)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you go diagonal or just right and down?

Comment: Did you had any course on graph theory ?

Comment: Only up left right and down sorry should've added that. @blckbird

Comment: No I have not taken anything on graph theory, this is a very beginning CS class. @Guiroux

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Writing `create_path`? (If your answer is "everything", you'll have to get help from your teacher and classmates, not us.)

Comment: Yes I only need the create_path I think I will be able to figure out where to go once I have a start.  @Beta

Comment: The first thing to think about is the interface. Suppose the user specifies (0,2)->(3,1). What should `create_path` pass to `print_path`?

Comment: I don't know that is why I am here @Beta

Comment: All right, try something easier: what *is* the shortest path from (0,2) to (3,1)?

Comment: right 3 down 1 @Beta

Comment: Good! And how did you arrive at that answer, and how would you express "right 3 down 1" in terms of, say, a pair of ints?

Comment: (3,1) - (0,2) but how do I get print_path to know where to start on the grid AND print each step until the marker gets to wanted destination

Comment: We're still discussing the interface, the information that `create_path` must pass to `print_path`. Two numbers describe the starting point (0,2), and two more describe the path (3, -1), agreed?

Comment: Now do you see how to write `create_path`? When given (0, 2, 3, 1), it must calculate (3, -1) and call `print_path(0, 2, 3, -1)`.

Comment: Yeah I see it now but I don't have enough time to figure out the print function now so I'm just going to go with a simpler solution that uses one other function.  Thanks for your help but people come here for answers not teachers. @Beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already pointed out yourself in the comments, the shortest path from (0,2) to (3,1) is "right 3 down 1" in other words: right 3-0=3 and down 2-1=1

And that's already pretty much the answer...

In general, how do find the shortest path from (xStart, yStart) to (xEnd, yEnd)? You just do the same thing as before again. It is "right xEnd-xStart, down yEnd-yStart".

So everything that the print_path function requires is just "where do I start" and "how much do I go right/left and how much do I go up/down?"

So you could use two variable in create_path

```
int right = xEnd-xStart;
int down = yEnd-yStart;
```

and you send these to print_path. You have not provided the signature of print_path, but it could look like this:

```
void print_path(int xStart, int yStart, int right, int down) 
{

}
```

Within this function you just do two loops:

```
int i = xStart;
int xend = xStart + right; // observe: if right is negative, it's just subtraction
bool right = (right >= 0); // are we going right or left?

while(i != xend) {
     std::cout << "next waypoint: x = " << i << ", y = " << yStart << std::endl;
     if (right) {
          i++;
     } else {
          i--;
     }
}
```

And now you do the same thing for the y coordinate

```
int j = yStart;
int yend = yStart + down; 
bool down = (down >= 0); // are we going down or up?

while(j != yend) {
     std::cout << "next waypoint: x = " << xend << ", y = " << j << std::endl;
     if (down) {
          j++;
     } else {
          j--;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.  I could see what I needed to do just after seeing the first couple of lines in print_path.  I wish I could get more straightforward answers like this that way my assignment would have been turned in on time.

Comment: I am sorry for you that I was too late. But I was thinking that you had more trouble with create_path than print path, which turned out to be wrong as you just said. Often it is best for stackoverflow to post solutions you already have, so that we know what it actually is that makes you stuck. It avoids explaining things that you already know, and gets to the point faster.

Answer (score -1):

**create_path** has to be a recursive function.

conditions given should be :

1. First check if the points are in the boundary or not
2. Then check if the point is the desired point, if yes then return
3. Otherwise recurse for up, down, left, right and diagonal points.

Comment: You want to do a recursive DFS to find something that is already *given as an argument?* That's the most inefficient solution I've seen in a long time.

Comment: We need to find the shortest path. So, what's wrong in it?

Comment: Try it. See how long it takes you to code it up and debug it, how many lines of code it requires, how many operations it must perform to find the answer, and how its run-time scales with the size of the grid.